# Dynamic queries in Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Since the Iron Router docs are nigh useless and the creators used to close issues before they were resolved (and now have apparently given up, just letting them sit there), this is a problem I can't find a solution for.

I need to set a dynamic query that would look something like this:

```
/person?name=Johnny
```

Which in a perfect world would be achieved this way:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'person' query='name=' + this.name}}">
```

Except this isn't a perfect world (we are talking about Iron Router, after all), so how do I actually do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well first things first I'd go ahead and do this:

`meteor remove passive:aggression`

That should help.

Secondly, what you're more or less going to have to do is pass the ID of the user to the iron:router, and then have it query the data base for a user with a matching ID. Once you've got tent he use object within iron:router, you'll be able to print whatever value you want into the url.

This tutorial by the Meteor Chef has a great walk through for doing something similar to what you're looking for [Slugged Routes](http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/slugged-routes)

Comment: Tried your first suggestion, didn't work. ;) Seriously though, how am I supposed to pass the `_id` to Iron Router without, uh, making a route of it? I ended up skipping `pathFor`, made things much simpler.

Comment: @Yeats There are quite a few steps to it, if I wasn't on mobile I'd rejig them to fit your problem specifically. Did you look at the article I linked? In it, the author does something extremely similar to what you're trying to do http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/slugged-routes/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple iron:router dynamic route:

```
Router.route('/person/:name',{
  name: 'person',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  data: function(){ // called once the subscription is ready
    return People.findOne({ name: this.params.name });
  },
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('getPerson',this.params.name); // assumes you need to ask the server for the document since you probably won't publish all people to every client
  }
});
```

The route will be available as `/person/name` rather than the parameter list style `/person?name=`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query params through to the route with the following:

```
{{pathFor 'person' query='name=Johnny'}}
```

Or pass it the value of a helper function like so

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    helperVal: function(){
        return "name="+this.name;
    }
});

//in template
{{pathFor 'person' query=helperVal}}
```

And then retrieve in the route itself like so...

```
this.params.query.name
```